# Rails route inconsistency and ActionController::RoutingError - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this error which show up and I did a lot of searching but can't seem to find the right solution. It works in one view and throws error on another view.

```
ActionController::RoutingError - No route matches {:action=>"status", :controller=>"orders", :status=>"canceled"}:
```

The error is being thrown from the following line

app/views/orders/_chef-states.html.erb - *partial*

```
    <%= link_to status_order_path(status: r.first.id2name),
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },
    method: :put,
    remote: true do %>
        <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
        <span><strong><%= r.first.id2name.capitalize %></strong></span>          
    <% end %>
```

the partial above is used in two places:

1. app/views/orders/show.html.erb
2. app/views/orders/chef.html.erb

In location one i.e show.html.erb it works perfectly fine but in location two it throws the routing error.

routes.rb

```
  resources :orders do
    member do
      put 'status'
      get 'print'
    end

    get 'chef' ,  on: :collection
  end
```

can someone suggest what might be the problem or how i could fix it.

complete log dump can be found here [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1S5pyYst)

Comment: I've answered this question of yours twice now, each time for a different question after you completely changed the content. And now your solution is something else entirely which we also couldn't see from the code you provided. Awesome.

Comment: Jon thanks for your answer, the only edit i made was adding the `method: :put` to the `link_to` and also Im not a expert at rails, when i figured what was the problem i shared it in answer. I hope you you won't call the police :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured the problem, in the second view (chef.html.erb) I was not passing order object since status is a member route on order controller.

confusing?

```
<%= render 'orders/chef-states', order: order %>
```

i missed the

```
 order: order
```

in the second view and it hence it was throwing the error, somehow the error message was not very self explanatory in this case.